# Need a function that adds together all items in a JSON array besides the last two

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make a function that adds together all items in an array besides the last two.

```
{"total_bx": 50000, "total_by": 10000, "total_either_sources": 59000, "total_all_sources": 5000}
```

The array is dynamic, and could contain bx/by or not. So functions like this don't work (which is what I have atm):

```
var APIData = JSON.parse(API.responseText);
  vwt = APIData.total_bx + APIData.total_by
  vwBx = (APIData.total_bx/vwt) * 100
  vwBy = (APIData.total_by/vwt) * 100
  appendData(APIData);
```

The JSON can be as long as 17 or as short as 3 items. I just need to add up what's in the array for my vwt attribute.

This is so I can dynamically drive the size of my visualisation using the actual array to append data.

Thanks.

Comment: There's no array in your question (and there's no such thing as a "JSON array" or "JSON object")

Comment: You've provided the input data, it would also be useful to provide us with what the output data _should_ look like. :)

Comment: Hey :) I'm not sure I understand. The first JSON is the API callback that provides the data. 

The output should be like this? 

var B10 = document.getElementById('b10');
B10.style.width = vwBanfield + 'vw'

So using the data above, the output should be 83.3333vw applied directly to the b10 id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the JSOn into a JS Object and iterate over the object properties. The properties do not have a well-defined order ( without recurse to the code where they have benn set), so you probably want to filter by the names of properties to be excluded:

```
let dict_exclude
  , n_sum = 0
  , o = JSON.parse(API.responseText)
  ;

dict_exclude = {
    total_either_sources: true
  , total_all_sources: true
};

for ( let [s_prop, n_value ] of Object.entries(o) ) {
    if (!dict_exclude.hasOwnProperty(s_prop) {
        n_sum += n_value;
    }
}

console.log("TL: " + n_sum);
```

Comment: Cheers :) This works to get the totals as I have asked. Thank you for understanding my request.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the keys from the object and use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to remove all, but the last 2 entries.

`let keys = Object.keys(data).slice(0, -2)`

and then use reduce to compute the sum:

`keys.reduce( (sum, key) => sum + obj[key], 0)`

This will lead to this oneliner

`Object.keys(data).slice(0, -2).reduce( (sum, key) => sum + data[key], 0)`

Note: the order of the keys is no guaranteed, so if you know the exact keys you want to remove then you should change `slice` with a `filter`.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like that ?
your question is really unclear!

```
let APIData  = JSON.parse(API.responseText)
 ,  total_bx = APIData.total_bx || 0
 ,  total_by = APIData.total_by || 0
 ;
APIData.vwt  =  total_bx + total_by
APIData.vwBx = (total_bx / APIData.vwt) * 100
APIData.vwBy = (total_by / APIData.vwt) * 100
```

Comment: Hey Jotaro, no this wasn't - I thought I mentioned that I had tried that out. I have an answer I like though, thanks.

Comment: @AliShahVis  Jotaro ?

Comment: You need to look up the culture behind the name Jojo. It is rich and vibrant.